# jQuery attach method on cloned element after appending to DOM tree

Tags: jquery, jquery-clone

Just quick question about the jquery-cloned element.
For a long time, I thought I have to re-jqueryfy cloned element after inserting it (to a DOM tree), but below code just works fine.

**HTML**

```
<div id="test">test<"/div>
<button id="btn">push</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var $clone = $('#test').clone(),
    $btn = $('#btn');

$clone.prop('id','clone').appendTo('body');

// I thought this is necessary but it's not.
// var $clone = $('#clone');
$btn.on('click',function(){
  $clone.toggleClass('someclass');
});
```

So can anybody tell me why?

Comment: Use `$clone.prop('id','clone')` instead of `$clone.attr('id','clone')`

Comment: Why should `$clone` loose its content after modifying it with `.attr()` and/or `.appendTo()`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you will see the docs for [jQuery `.clone()` method](https://api.jquery.com/clone/), this method creates a deep copy of the set of matched elements.

So when you clone the element, the `clone` method returns the copy of the element. And even if you appending the same into the body again, the reference of the copied element is still held in the variable. So you don't need to get it again to manipulate it.

You can understand:

```
var $clone = $('#test').clone();
// you created the copy of the $('#test') element and held it in $clone variable
$clone.attr('id','clone').appendTo('body'); // you should prefer prop() instead
// you changed it's id but it is still held in $clone
$clone.toggleClass('someclass');
// and you can toggle it's class as it is still held in $clone variable
```

Comment: So it means jQuery keeps track wherever the cloned element goes? I thought if it gets appended or prepended in somewhere in DOM tree, it's done, this `$clone` object will never be updated. So if this is how it works, I can swallow as is and I was wrong about jQuery object in my entire jQuery life :(

Comment: It's not about jQuery but it is about JavaScript that how variables work in JavaScript. You can read more about jQuery `.clone()` method [here](https://api.jquery.com/clone/).

Comment: OK thanks. I will try to do same in vanilla JS if I get same result.